# Scala Cross Cutting Concerns with mixin composition stacks

Tags: scala, mixins, aspect

I was following along [this](http://jonasboner.com/real-world-scala-managing-cross-cutting-concerns-using-mixin-composition-and-aop/) tutorial by Jonas Bonér on how to achieve AspectJ like aspect oriented programming in Scala. The mixins got me quite confused with the `abstract overrides`. I eventually got the implementation working by matching `parsePointcutExpression`. However, The `pointcutExpression` matching is incorrect:

My Invocation case class:

```
package aspect2

import java.lang.reflect.Method

object aspect {
  case class Invocation(val method: Method, val args: Array[AnyRef], val target: AnyRef) {
    def invoke: AnyRef = method.invoke(target, args:_*)
    override def toString: String = "Invocation [method: " + method.getName + ", args: " + args + ", target: " + target + "]"

  }

}
```

My interceptor and advice methods for matching `pointcutExpressions` and logging: Note I want to match against `"execution(* *.bar(..))"`.

```
package aspect2

import aspect2.aspect.Invocation
import org.aspectj.weaver.tools.{PointcutExpression, PointcutParser}
object InterceptorImpl {
  trait Interceptor {
    protected val parser = PointcutParser.getPointcutParserSupportingAllPrimitivesAndUsingContextClassloaderForResolution
    protected def matches(pointcut: PointcutExpression, invocation: Invocation): Boolean = {
      pointcut.matchesMethodExecution(invocation.method).alwaysMatches ||
        invocation.target.getClass.getDeclaredMethods.exists(pointcut.matchesMethodExecution(_).alwaysMatches) ||
        false
    }
    def invoke(invocation: Invocation): AnyRef
  }
  trait LoggingInterceptor extends Interceptor {
    val loggingPointcut = parser.parsePointcutExpression("execution(* *.bar(..))")

    abstract override def invoke(invocation: Invocation): AnyRef =
      if (matches(loggingPointcut , invocation)) {
        println("=====> Enter: " + invocation.method.getName + " @ " + invocation.target.getClass.getName)
        val result = super.invoke(invocation)
        println("=====> Exit: " + invocation.method.getName + " @ " + invocation.target.getClass.getName)
        result
      } else super.invoke(invocation)
  }


}
```

My factory methods to wire in the interceptors using `Java Dynamic Proxy API`

```
package aspect2

import java.lang.reflect.{InvocationHandler, Method, Proxy}

import aspect2.aspect.Invocation

object ManagedComponentFactory {
  def createComponent[T](intf: Class[T] forSome {type T}, proxy: ManagedComponentProxy): T =
    Proxy.newProxyInstance(
      proxy.target.getClass.getClassLoader,
      Array(intf),
      proxy).asInstanceOf[T]
}

class ManagedComponentProxy(val target: AnyRef) extends InvocationHandler {
  override def invoke(proxy: AnyRef, m: Method, args: Array[AnyRef]): AnyRef = invoke(Invocation(m, args, target))
  def  invoke(invocation: Invocation): AnyRef = invocation.invoke
}
```

My main function to run the demo:

```
package aspect2

import aspect2.InterceptorImpl.LoggingInterceptor
import aspect2.aspect.Invocation

object aspectDemo  extends App{
  var foo = ManagedComponentFactory.createComponent[Foo](
    classOf[Foo],
    new ManagedComponentProxy(new FooImpl)
      with LoggingInterceptor{
    override def invoke(invocation:Invocation):AnyRef={
      super.invoke(invocation)
    }
  })

  foo.foo("foo")
  foo.bar("bar")
}
```

Foo and Bar are implemented as follows:

```
trait Foo {
  def foo(msg: String)
  def bar(msg: String)
}

class FooImpl extends Foo {
  val bar: Bar = new BarImpl
  def foo(msg: String) = println("msg: " + msg)
  def bar(msg: String) = bar.bar(msg)
}

trait Bar {
  def bar(msg: String)
}

class BarImpl extends Bar {
  def bar(msg: String) = println("msg: " + msg)
}
```

My results show that my pointcut (`"execution(* *.bar(..))"`) gets both `foo.bar("bar") and foo.foo("foo")`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the line `invocation.target.getClass.getDeclaredMethods.exists(pointcut.matchesMethodExecution(_).alwaysMatches)` in the `object InterceptorImpl` which matches all methods of the class. Since both methods `foo` and `bar` belong to `trait Foo` which is extended by `class FooImpl` the `pointcutExpression` matches logging happens for both methods.